# React native app(just created) crashes with following error messages when install packages like react-native-gesture handle

Tags: android, react-native

error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup.
Error: Command failed: gradlew.bat app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081

FAILURE: Build completed with 2 failures.

### 1: Task failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Build file 'E:\React_native\paperboy\node_modules\react-native-gesture-handler\android\build.gradle' line: 27
- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred evaluating project ':react-native-gesture-handler'.

> Could not initialize class org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.plugin.sources.DefaultKotlinSourceSetKt

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
> ==============================================================================

### 2: Task failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred configuring project ':react-native-gesture-handler'.

> compileSdkVersion is not specified. Please add it to build.gradle

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
> ==============================================================================

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 14s

```
at makeError (E:\React_native\paperboy\node_modules\execa\index.js:174:9)
at E:\React_native\paperboy\node_modules\execa\index.js:278:16
at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
at async runOnAllDevices (E:\React_native\paperboy\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\build\commands\runAndroid\runOnAllDevices.js:109:5)
at async Command.handleAction (E:\React_native\paperboy\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli\build\index.js:192:9)
```

info Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.

Comment: I am having the same issue, were you able to resolve it?

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove the `if..else` condition in your `build.gradle` file under the `signingConfigs` > `release`.
Example:

```
    signingConfigs {
        debug {
            storeFile file('debug.keystore')
            storePassword 'android'
            keyAlias 'androiddebugkey'
            keyPassword 'android'
        }
        release {
            storeFile file('xxx')
            storePassword 'xxx'
            keyAlias 'xxx'
            keyPassword 'xxx'
        }
    }
```

Comment: there is no if..else in the signingconfig section. it looks exactly like your example.